# sequelize - how to find multiple related items of the same type

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, foreign-keys, sequelize-typescript

I have a table with some relations that are of the same type.
There are two tables `UserCollection` and `ImagenProcess`

UserCollection has two instances of ImagenProcess.
The IDs when read are unique, but when I try to 'include' to get the related data, I get duplicates.

### UserCollection

```
export class UserCollection extends Model<Partial<UserCollection>> {

    // actually the user nickname
    @Column({
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    })
    id!: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => ImagenProcess)
    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        allowNull: true,
    })
    uniqueImageId: string;
    @BelongsTo(() => ImagenProcess)
    uniqueImage: ImagenProcess

    @ForeignKey(() => ImagenProcess)
    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        allowNull: true,
    })
    commonImageId: string;
    @BelongsTo(() => ImagenProcess)
    commonImage: ImagenProcess
```

### ImagenProcess

```
export class ImagenProcess extends Model<Partial<ImagenProcess>> {
    @Column({
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataType.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4
    })
    id!: string;
    ...
```

And i'm fetching with an include like:

```
        const userCollection = await UserCollection.findOne({
            where: {
                id
            },
            include: [
                'uniqueImage',
                'rareImage',
                'commonImage',
            ]
        })
```

however I get this (edited for brevity):

```
 userCollection {
  "id": "dc",
  "uniqueImageId": "37803940-dad0-45c9-9d74-8cafbe06bc24",
  "commonImageId": "e6b5944d-1c24-46fa-8c68-79725ea08514",
  "uniqueImage": {
    "id": "37803940-dad0-45c9-9d74-8cafbe06bc24",
  },
  "commonImage": {
    "id": "37803940-dad0-45c9-9d74-8cafbe06bc24",
  }
}
```

so note that the raw data `uniqueImageId` and `commonImageId` are correct (different from each other):

```
"uniqueImageId": "37803940-dad0-45c9-9d74-8cafbe06bc24",
"commonImageId": "e6b5944d-1c24-46fa-8c68-79725ea08514",
```

But the returned relation blobs are a duplicate...

```
  "uniqueImage": {
    "id": "37803940-dad0-45c9-9d74-8cafbe06bc24",
  },
  "commonImage": {
    "id": "37803940-dad0-45c9-9d74-8cafbe06bc24",
  }
```

Is there some limitation or bug known here?

Tried to simplify the above, but the summary is:
One table contains relations with named fields, to two instances of another table.
The IDs are unique, but when using `includes` I get duplicates of the first item.

Answer (score 0):

The findAll() method, by default, will return all attributes of the table you are querying. In this case, it returns id, uniqueImageId, and commonImageId.

By adding the include, you add JOINs to the query, and by default this will return all attributes of the models you are joining with. All of these attributes returned go inside of the appropriate object. In this case, it appears that your uniqueImage and commonImage tables only have id columns (And I'm not sure where the rareImage data is coming from at all. It's a duplicate value to the uniqueImage, but you didn't share any of the table or model code that defines rareImage).

I suspect that your UserCollection model has uniqueImageId and commonImageId defined as attributes PLUS has the associations defined. If this is the case, you can remove the attribute definitions and the query will not return those values on the top-level. You would then only get those values when they are specified to be included. You can also leave those attributes defined, but specify an "exclude" in the query options that will leave uniqueImageId and commonImageId out.

Side note to your original question: I'm not sure if you have future plans to expand the uniqueImage and commonImage tables, but as it stands right now, there are definitely questions in my mind about the necessity of them existing. CommonImage sounds like it may merit its own table if different users share them, but uniqueImage sounds like it could just be a column in UserCollection rather than its own table.

Comment: updated to clarify `uniqueImage` and `commonImage` both point to the same table: `imagenProcess` although different records. I put definitions of both above. This works as far as IDs, but not when I `include` the relation - then I just get dupes.